# AngularJS delay loading data from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, .htaccess

I'm using angular in a simple application like:

**app.js**

```
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("NavCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    var serviceBase = 'v1/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'orderoverview/58').then(function (results) {
        $scope.categories = results.data;
        $scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
        var categories = $scope.categories[i];
        total += (categories.productPrice * categories.orderdetailAantal);
        if(categories.extra1 != "")
        {
          total += categories.extrasPrice;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Served</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-cloak="">

<div class="navbar navbar-default megamenu">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat= "p in categories">{{p.orderdetailAantal}} x {{p.productTitle}} {{p.productPrice}} <br> {{p.extra1}} {{p.extra2}} {{p.extra3}} {{p.extra4}} {{p.extrasPrice}}</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Total: {{ getTotal() }} euro</p>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this works but every time I load the page there is a delay of almost 3 seconds to get the data from the db and show it in my html page...
When I surf directly to the API, I built using PHP, the required data is shown instantly...

How is this possible and how can I speed up this proces?

(if needed, my API and .htaccess)

**API**

```
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

$app->get('/orderoverview/:customerID', function ($customerID) {

$sql = "SELECT `customerName` FROM `customers` WHERE `customerID` = $customerID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $customername = $row["customerName"];
    }
} 
else {
    echo "Customer name failure";
}

$sql = "SELECT `orderID` FROM `order` WHERE `customerID` = $customerID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 1){
    echo "You already have a pending order! <br>";
}
else if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $orderID = $row["orderID"];
    }
    step2($orderID, $customername);
} else {
    echo "GET orderID failure";
}
});
$app->run();

function step2($orderID, $customername){

mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `orderdetailID` FROM `orderdetail` WHERE `orderID` = '$orderID'");
$results = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
}
step3($orderID, $results, $customername);
}

function step3($orderID, $results, $customername){
global $conn, $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;

$to = 0;
$extracounter = 1;
$extrasprice = 0;

foreach($results as $key=>$odt)
{
    $extracounter = 1;

    $odb = $odt["orderdetailID"];
    $sql = "SELECT `productID`, `orderdetailAantal` FROM `orderdetail` WHERE `orderdetailID` = '$odb'";
    $sql2 = "SELECT `extraID` FROM `orderdetailextra` WHERE `orderdetailID` = '$odb'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $sql3 = "SELECT `productTitle` FROM `products` WHERE `productID` = '$row[productID]'";
            $sql4 = "SELECT `productPrijs` FROM `products` WHERE `productID` = '$row[productID]'";

            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
            if($result3->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row1 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
                    $productTitle = $row1["productTitle"];
                }
            } 

            $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
            if($result4->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row1 = $result4->fetch_assoc()){
                    $productPrice = $row1["productPrijs"];
                }
            } 

            $order[$to] = array(
                "orderdetailID" => $odb,
                "productTitle" => $productTitle,
                "productPrice" => $productPrice,                
                "orderdetailAantal" => $row["orderdetailAantal"],
                "extra1" => "",
                "extra2" => "",
                "extra3" => "",
                "extra4" => "",
                "extrasPrice" => ""
            );
            $to++;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'fout sql 1';
    }                

            }
        }

    }

}
    echoResponse(200, $order);

}
function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
    global $app;
    $app->status($status_code);
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

**.HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteBase /localsites/serf/weap/api/v1
```

Comment: you need to use resolve parameter in the route so that your view is not set until that required values are reached. You cant speed up the process as your execution of app.js is after your html. So your html will load first and then only your js files, which is a good practise. So use resolve that will solve this.

Comment: Could you give an example to back up your solution? I can't seem to get it right...

Comment: you need to use resolve with route. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider                         This will give you an answer         http://embed.plnkr.co/VOymS4/app.js